# Unexpected " unexpected '}' "

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to get to my local site, after uploading new theme, I get the message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\test03\wp-content\themes\hazera\inc\all-to-pdf.php on line 52

This is the code:

```
<? function to_pdf_form(){ ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input style="margin-top:20px;" class="button" type="submit" name="submit-all-to-pdf" value="Upload all products to PDF!">
    </form>
    <p>Files uploaded to /wp-content/uploads/products-pdf.</p>



<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['submit-all-to-pdf']) ){
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

        global $post;
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
        $the_product = get_posts( $args );  
        foreach( $the_product as $post ) {
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product_name = get_the_title ( $product_id );

        if(class_exists('Pdfcrowd')){
            if ( !$product_id ) die();
            $pdf_version_url = add_query_arg( array('pdf_version' => 1), get_permalink($product_id));
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            if (!file_exists($wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/products-pdf')) {
                mkdir($wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/products-pdf', 0777, true);
            }
            $pdf_file_name = 'product-' . $product_id . '.pdf';
            $pdf_file_path = $wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/products-pdf/' . $pdf_file_name;

            try
            {

                // create an API client instance
                $client = new Pdfcrowd("username", "password");
                if ( file_exists( $pdf_file_path ) ) continue;
                $out_file = fopen($pdf_file_path, "wb");
                $client->setHtmlZoom("120");
                $client->convertURI($pdf_version_url, $out_file);
                fclose($out_file);

                // send the generated PDF
                echo '<strong>' . $product_name .' uploaded successfully. </strong><br/>'; 
            }
            catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
            {
                echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why . "<br/>";
            }
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

I don't see what's wrong here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You are using short open tags such as this:

```
<? function to_pdf_form(){ ?>
```

change to this

```
<?php function to_pdf_form(){ ?>
```

and you shouldn't have any issues.

---

This is wrong, ignore it:

You have an extra closing `}` here, remove it

```
catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
    {
        echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why . "<br/>";
    }
    //}
```